# OS EXL 10.11.6, Difference in Mail Box size and its size on Hard disk

Tags: macbook-pro

I am having a Macbook Air and using OS EXL 1.11.6. The mail box size is 164 GB but on Hard Disk its showing 267 GB. This extra usage is eating my hard disk space.

Please suggest why is this and how to clear this extra space used on hard disk.

Comment: email attachments maybe ?

Comment: Actually, what i feel that my inbox is getting stored at 2 locations may be auto backup. How can I resolve that duplication of data..